# [azure-ad-b2b]Need a way to bypass the consent/review prompt when Guest users access the application

Tags: azure-ad-b2b

Scenario: Two tenants a.onmicrosoft.com and b.onmicrosoft.com
user from b.onmicrosoft.com would like to access the application in a.onmicrosoft.com

Option 1: To send an invitation email, the user needs to redeem the invitation and then access it.
Option 2: To bypass the invitation Email using Graph API or powershell but still the user will need to review the permissions and accept the terms /conditions before accessing the application.

[Review Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bELDI.png)

Goal: End users should be able to access the application without going through the invitation Email or review permissions. Can this be taken care of at the Tenant level of the Resource Tenant where the application is hosted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end user can't avoid this consent screen (review permissions), this consent screen feature was introduced in [2018](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/exciting-improvements-to-the-b2b-collaboration-experience/ba-p/245409). Please verify the tech community link.